RunRequest object not accepting target argument in dagster workflow (job@run_status_sensor)
I have a sensor that I want to trigger a job run after an upstream job finishes. here is my sensor definition(removed config details).
from dagster import run_status_sensor, RunRequest, SkipReason, DagsterRunStatus
from analytics.jobs.etl_job import dbt_job
@run_status_sensor(run_status=DagsterRunStatus.SUCCESS)
def trigger_dbt_job_after_etl(context):
    context.log.info(f"Sensor triggered for job: {context.dagster_run.job_name}")
    
    if context.dagster_run.job_name == "etl_job":
        context.log.info("etl_job completed successfully. Preparing to trigger dbt_job.")
        
        run_config = {
            "ops": {
                "run_dbt_task": {
                    "config": {
                        "cluster_name": "",
                        "launch_type": "",
                        "security_groups": [""],
                        "subnets": [
                            "subnet-",
                            "subnet-",
                            "subnet-",
                            "subnet-",
                            "subnet-"
                        ],
                        "task_definition": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        # Create the RunRequest and log its contents
        run_request = RunRequest(run_key=None, run_config=run_config, job=dbt_job, job_name="dbt_job")
        context.log.info(f"Created RunRequest: {run_request}")
        return run_request
    else:
        context.log.info(f"Skipping sensor run because the job is not etl_job. Current job: {context.dagster_run.job_name}")
        return SkipReason("The job is not etl_job, skipping.")

and I get the following traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_daemon/sensor.py", line 471, in _process_tick_generator
    yield from _evaluate_sensor(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_daemon/sensor.py", line 614, in _evaluate_sensor
    sensor_runtime_data = code_location.get_external_sensor_execution_data(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/remote_representation/code_location.py", line 930, in get_external_sensor_execution_data
    return sync_get_external_sensor_execution_data_grpc(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_api/snapshot_sensor.py", line 87, in sync_get_external_sensor_execution_data_grpc
    raise DagsterUserCodeProcessError.from_error_info(result.error)
dagster._core.errors.DagsterUserCodeProcessError: dagster._core.errors.SensorExecutionError: Error occurred during the execution of evaluation_fn for sensor trigger_dbt_job_after_etl

Stack Trace:
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_grpc/impl.py", line 400, in get_external_sensor_execution
    return sensor_def.evaluate_tick(sensor_context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/errors.py", line 297, in user_code_error_boundary
    raise new_error from e

The above exception was caused by the following exception:
Exception: Error in sensor trigger_dbt_job_after_etl: Sensor evaluation function returned a RunRequest for a sensor lacking a specified target (job_name, job, or jobs). Targets can be specified by providing job, jobs, or job_name to the @sensor decorator.

Stack Trace:
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/errors.py", line 287, in user_code_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_grpc/impl.py", line 400, in get_external_sensor_execution
    return sensor_def.evaluate_tick(sensor_context)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/sensor_definition.py", line 921, in evaluate_tick
    *self.resolve_run_requests(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/sensor_definition.py", line 965, in resolve_run_requests
    raise Exception(

I believe I'm correctly adding the sensor to my init file/definitions
from dagster import Definitions, EnvVar
from analytics.jobs.etl_job import etl_job, dbt_job
from analytics.resources.ecs_resource import ecs_client  
from analytics.sensors.job_sensor import trigger_dbt_job_after_etl


defs = Definitions(
    jobs=[etl_job, dbt_job],  
    resources={
        "ecs_client": ecs_client.configured({
            "region_name":"us-east-1",
            "aws_access_key_id":"",
            "aws_secret_access_key":""
            } )
            },
    sensors=[trigger_dbt_job_after_etl]
            )

After reviewing dagster docs it seems pretty straightforward to pass a target to a RunRequest but not sure why its not recognizing it at runtime?
the returned runrequest object looks correct
Created RunRequest: RunRequest(run_key=None, run_config={'ops': {'run_dbt_task': {'config': {'cluster_name': 'dbt-', 'launch_type': 'FARGATE', 'security_groups': ['sg-'], 'subnets': ['subnet-', 'subnet-', 'subnet-', 'subnet-', 'subnet-'], 'task_definition': 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:'}}}}, tags={}, job_name='dbt_job', asset_selection=None, stale_assets_only=False, partition_key=None, asset_check_keys=None, asset_graph_subset=None)


I figured out that the request_job parameter needed to be added to the sensor decorator. its triggering now

I figured out that the request_job parameter needed to be added to the sensor decorator. its triggering now
